# How the arc length of sine wave is calculated?

Tags: trigonometry

According to [this site](http://www.intmath.com/applications-integration/11-arc-length-curve.php) the arc length of the curve $y = f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is given by:

$$\operatorname{length}_{ab} = {\large\int}_a^b \!\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx.$$
So, we got a sine wave function which is 
$$y = \left. A\sin (Fx + P) \right|_{x=a}^b.$$

the length of this is

$$\operatorname{length}_{\text{sine}} = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+(AF\cos(Fx))^2}\,dx $$

Example of this is in first link or [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tell%20me%20the%20arc%20length%20of%20y%20=%201.35%2asin%280.589x%29%20from%20x%20=%200%20to%2010.67):

> Now, my question is: what is the algorithm to compute length for specified $x=a$ to $x=b$?

For example, let's say:

step 1) set length = $0$;

step 2) for $x = a$ to $x = b$ {
        increase $x$ by $0.01$;
        length = length + derivative($x$);
    }

step 3) return length;

I have implemented such a function, but it gives me the wrong length according to wolfram. Is it because of the increasing $x$ or wrong derivative function?

Thanks in advance!
Regards!

Comment: Wrong derivative, it is $AF\cos(FX+P)$. Also, you want to integrate, so it is integral from $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $A\sin(Fx+P)$ is $AF\cos(Fx+P)$. Also, you want to integrate, so it is integral from $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Your step 2 is wrong.  It should be
$$x \leftarrow x + \underbrace{0.01}_{dx}$$
$$\text{Length} \leftarrow \text{Length} + \underbrace{0.01}_{dx} \cdot \sqrt{1 + \text{Derivative}(x)^2}$$

Be sure use the derivative that Andre Nicolas corrected.

Also, if the integral looks confusing, look how it can be rewritten:

$$L = \int \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$$

$$dL = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$$

$$dL^2 = \left(1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right) dx^2$$

$$dL^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$$

...which should look very familiar.